# Writing SQL queries in XML

Tags: asp.net, xml, teradata

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11178/Writing-SQL-queries-in-XML-A-support-intensive-app

[ASP.NET - Storing SQL Queries in Global Resource File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270611/asp-net-storing-sql-queries-in-global-resource-file)

I want to do something like the above link...but it is not working for me..

I have dynamic sql in my project which i want to move to xml. Can some one please help?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? Why move something that works? Can you please details what database and version you are using?

Comment: SELECT BookingID from BOOKING WHERE BOOKINGDATE >= {0}...I want a query in xml, database is teradata...they dont want to create sp...i have to create dynamic queries in asp.net...but they suggested me to use the query in xml....

Comment: Please _edit_ the question to add details - don't post in comments (both because you loose formatting, and because people are less likely to read comments).

Comment: Why would using XML help? Who is "they" in "they don't want to crate sp"?

Comment: I dont know why they dont want to use sp...please suggest me how to save the dynamic queries in asp.net

Answer (score 2):

I really hope that you saying you want to store "SELECT BookingID from BOOKING WHERE BOOKINGDATE >= {0}" doesn't mean you are planning on writing:

```
String.Format(query, parameter)
```

That's a huge security vulnerability.

Edit:

If you really want to go down this route I would suggest Xml like:

```
 <queries>
   <query id="getBookingId">
     <parameters>
       <parameter name="bookingDate" />
     </parameters>
     <statement>
       <!-- 
          SELECT BookingID from BOOKING WHERE BOOKINGDATE >= @bookingDate
       -->
     </statement>
   </query>
 </queries>
```

Then you can have a class:

```
[XmlElement("query")]
public sealed class Query 
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    // other elements/collections
}
```

You can then deserialize your Xml into a collection of these Query objects. I would recommend doing this once and storing it in an IDictionary somewhere to avoid repeatedly processing an Xml file.

You then have everything you need in each Query object. A collection of parameters and the sql statement - note that you'll have to manually strip the comment characters () out of the statement before using. Again, probably best to do this once at the beginning.

Comment: so, how should i fix my probelm? where should i save my dynamic query?